# SVG в Android приложении

Tags: android, android-studio

```
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appLogoView"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:src="@drawable/app_logo"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
            android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="false" />
```

Файл app_logo.svg в drawable размещен, но изображение не отображается в приложении и Android Studio строку **android:src="@drawable/app_logo"** красным не выделяет.

В чем проблема?

Comment: формат SVG не поддерживается Android/ Перед использованием нужно конвертировать в формат VectorDrawable. В Android Studio есть инструмент для этого - Vector Asset Studio

Answer (score 4):

Файлы svg и psd нужно добавлять в Vector Asset Studio, которая преобразует их в xml фаил. В Android Studio правой кнопкой кликни по папке "res", и там выбери: "New > Vector Asset". Дальше выбирай "Local file". Дальше просто указываешь имя, жмешь некст. Подробно тут: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#importing